# In tensorflow, how to calculate sequence loss using output from dynamic_decode

Tags: tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

Hi fellow Tensorflowers,

I am trying to implement a sequence-to-sequence model using the new `seq2seq` module that is under development and release with `TF1.0` and `1.1`.
There is a [`dynamic_decode`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/dynamic_decode) function that returns logits in the form of a `rnn_output.

Then, I need to calculate loss using the output of the RNN.

When I run it naively, just by calling `tf.contrib.seq2seq.loss.sequence_loss` with `(rnn_output, weights, logits)` it crashes with:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1856,1,1024] vs. [9600,1,1024]
         [[Node: optimize/gradients/loss/sequence_loss/sampled_softmax_loss/Mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](optimize/gradients/loss/sequence_loss/sampled_softmax_loss/Mul_grad/Shape/_3099, optimize/gradients/loss/sequence_loss/sampled_softmax_loss/Mul_grad/Shape_1/_3101)]]
         [[Node: optimize/gradients/Add/_824 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2787_optimize/gradients/Add", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:3"](^_cloopMainDynamicDecoderWithAttention/decoder/decoder/while/BasicDecoderStep/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/zeros/_128)]]
```

Which is natural, since `rnn_output` is *dynamically shaped*.

I have two possible solutions:

1. "pack" dynamic tensor into a tensor of size equal to the maximum allowed length. I don't know how to pack a dynamic tensor into a tensor of fixed size, but it probably has to do with new interfaces for dynamic shape: `tf.while_loop` and `TensorArrays`. It would be great to hear some advice on that
2. Dynamically calculate sequence_loss. But my knowledge of inner tensorflow implementation is too limited to assess correctly whether it's something easy to do. Any suggestions here?

**The general question**

What is the right approach to calculate sampled/normal softmax cross-entropy loss from dynamically shaped `rnn_output` of `dynamic_decode`?

I have the following code:

```
decoder_outputs, decoder_state = seq2seq.dynamic_decode(my_decoder, output_time_major=False, parallel_iterations=512,
                   swap_memory = True)

self.logits = decoder_outputs.rnn_output
self.loss = loss.sequence_loss(self.logits, tf.transpose(tf.stack(targets), [1,0], name="targets_"),
                                                 tf.transpose(tf.stack(self.target_weights), [1,0], name="weights_"),
                                                 softmax_loss_function = softmax_loss_function)
```

> ipdb> tf.**version** '1.1.0-rc0'

python: 2.7

Comment: Did you manage to find some solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's a trouble with tf.contrib.seq2seq.loss.sequence_loss, for sure.
If you use dynamic RNNs and don't unroll your BPTT manually, you may use much simplier loss function.

What I did, is basically:

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=self.answers,
        logits=presoftmax
    )
)/self.batch_sz
```

I know, it's not purely scientific. You'll need to shape it for your task. It's just a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using GreedyEmbeddingHelper? During training, you should use TF's "TrainingHelper". The output dimension should match your target dimension because at ever time step, the target is used as your input.